# Normalizing sample data to unit variance

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose you have data points $X_1,...,X_n$ drawn from some distribution $\mathbb{P}$ (regard them as iid random variables) and let the distribution be "well-behaved" so that the mean is $\mu$ and variance is $\sigma^2$. Now suppose that we want to normalize our data, i.e., find a mapping $X_i \mapsto Y_i$ such that $Y_i$ are iid drawn from a distribution with mean $=0$ and variance $1$. Suppose that we don't know the true values $\mu,\sigma^2$, then it's not too hard to make the mean zero by using the map
$$
X_i \mapsto Y_i\equiv X_i -\hat{\mu}, \quad\hat{\mu} \equiv \frac1n \sum_1^n X_i
$$
Indeed, $\hat{\mu}$ is the sample mean and it's quite easy to check that
$$
\mathbb{E}Y_i =0
$$
Now if I would want to do the same for the variance, the natural method would be something like
$$
X_i \mapsto Y_i \equiv \frac{X_i -\hat{\mu}}{\hat{\sigma}}, \quad\hat{\sigma}^2 \equiv \frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i -\hat{\mu})^2
$$
Now we know by the convergence in distribution, that when $n\to \infty$, we see that $Y_i\to (X_i -\mu)/\sigma$ in distribution, but the variance doesn't seem to be normalized for arbitrary $n$.

**Question**. Is is actually possible to normalize the variance of a sample data set without knowing the true mean and variance?

**EDIT**. To be specific, I want to normalize $X_i$ so that it's population variance is $=1$, not it's sample variance. Indeed,
$$
\mathbb{E} (X_i -\hat{\mu}) =0
$$
So similarly, I would hope that
$$
\mathbb{E} Y_i^2 = 1
$$
Where $Y_i= f_i(X_1,...,X_n)$. What is $f_i$?

Comment: The $Y_i$ set has a sample variance of 1.  I don't see the problem.

Comment: It happens all the time, standard practice.

Comment: (1) The $Y_i$ do __not__ tend to normal. The $\hat \mu$ are asymptotically normal. (2) In short: you cannot find a normalisation for the variance contrary to the mean, mainly because while the mean is additive, the variance is not and any normalisation by a random quantity will not "come out" of the expectation as a constant would.

Comment: @WilliamM. (1). Good catch. Instead, it should converge in distribution to the "normalized $X$", i.e., $Y_i \to (X_i-\mu)/\sigma$ where $\mu,\sigma$ are the true values. (2). Maybe there's a nonlinear function $f_i$?

Comment: As far as I know, you don't normalise in general; the best you can hope for is to assume $X$ from some specific distribution and then find "statistics" from the sample $\hat t = f(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ such that $\hat t$ has a "known" distribution and $\hat t (X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ (scalar times vector) has a "canonical version" of a "known" distribution.

Comment: I believe the classical example is the $F$-distribution where if $X \sim \mathsf{Norm}(\mu, \sigma^2)$ then you consider two independent samples, then construct $F = \sum (X_{1,i} - \hat \mu_1)^2 / \sum (X_{2,j} - \hat \mu_2)^2$ and the $\sigma$ "cancel" out, so that $F$ is a distribution independent of both $\mu$ and $\sigma$! This is actually done in ordinary linear regression. I suspect similar approaches are done in the generalised linear models (where they assume distributions other than the normal).

Comment: Just a final comment. The famous Behrens-Fisher problem is similar to what you are asking: two samples each with their own variance. Here there is no trick to "cancel out" the unknown $\sigma$ and therefore the problem is largely open. There are many partial solutions and partial interpretations, but there is not a single one approach that is satisfactory: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behrens%E2%80%93Fisher_problem

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to "normalize" the data so that the sample mean is $0$ and the sample variance is $1$, but normalizing based on the sample mean and variance causes problems for the independence of the resulting statistics, because each post-map observation depends on sample statistics, which in turn depend on the other observation. This interdependence causes the sample variance to, on average, be smaller than the population variance, if we calculate the sample variance as $\frac{1}n \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i -\hat{\mu})^2$. This is why the formula $\frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i -\hat{\mu})^2$ is generally used. So we either use the formula with $n$ in the denominator, in which case we're not getting what we would get from the base distribution, or we use $n-1$, in which case our sample variance is not going to be $1$. And neither choice for the denominator addresses the interdependence issue (this issue is also why we use a t-distribution rather than a normal one for hypothesis testing when the base distribution is normal).